# ros2 way to transform pointCloud2

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

does anybody know how to transform point clouds in ros2?
Or maybe any workaround?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392791/ros2-way-to-transform-pointcloud2/) by [dieteralfons](https://answers.ros.org/users/88903/dieteralfons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [repository](https://github.com/SebastianGrans/ROS2-Point-Cloud-Demo) from
[SebastianGrans](http://sebastiangrans.github.io/) has a nice ROS2 PointCloud demo publisher and a subscriber (in Python). It could be the base for your work, I hope.

Some examples of working with transforming a PointCloud are [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFNikTHN1pk) (ROS1, pointcloud to laserscan-like) and in this [package](https://index.ros.org/p/pcl_ros/) (PCL (Point Cloud Library) ROS interface stack). The last one could be your best choice.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2021-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dieteralfons](https://answers.ros.org/users/88903/dieteralfons/) on 2021-12-16**:
thanks.

pcl_ros::transformPointCloud did the trick